# How to recache a simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

**What is the proper way to re-cache a simulation?** I got the problem during Cloth and Fluid simulations that the cache is ignoring my new adjustments in the parameters. I'd like to just switch off 'cache mode' so I can freely experiment with some parameters without constantly punch myself to the head why there are no changes noticeable in my simulation.

Comment: jspr, all you need to do is delete your cache, add changes and bake it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Fluids:**

Select the domain object -> Physics tab -> Fluid -> Settings -> Free Data

Then don't forget to re-bake the Mesh and Particles.

**For Cloth:**

Select a cloth object -> Physics tab -> Cloth -> Cache -> Delete All Bakes

Then Bake again.